# Spring boot: removed spring security dependency from pom-xml but still generating password in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, maven-3

Initially, I have added spring security dependency in an application but later removed but still it generating the password. Maven clean install did not work. I have also removed .idea and project.iml. But still have no clue how to prevent it.  [image: spring]

Comment: Which dependency have you added and removed? Run [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) command to find out which module this dependency comes from.

Comment: @Andrey the dependency is spring.security artifact and there is no external dependency where this dependency is coming from. I am guessing this is something wrong with the IntelliJ setting. Because from pom.xml this dependency is removed but still showing in effective-pom-xml which I am not able to edit.

Comment: `still showing in effective-pom-xml` this means it is a Maven which adds it there, not the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue lately, to solve it I did the following:

1. In IntelliJ, go to the "Maven" tab.
2. Click on "Reload All Maven Projects."

[image: This button on the maven tab:]

This action forces IntelliJ to refresh and update all the Maven dependencies used in your project. Sometimes, even after removing a dependency from the pom.xml file, the IDE may still rely on cached dependency files, leading to unexpected behavior.

By reloading all Maven projects, you ensure that IntelliJ fetches the latest dependencies and eliminates any remnants of the previously removed Spring Security dependency.